# Rename multiple files in multiple sub folders using python

Tags: python, loops, directory, rename

Beginer python coder here.

I've been struggling with this problem for few days now and finally given up and seeking help.

Problem illustrated:

```
All Student folders:
Student a: 
    Work.pdf
    Work2.pdf
Student b:
    Work.pdf
    Work2.pdf
```

Folders `Student a` and `student b`, contain two files each.
I need to rename those files as homework1.pdf and homework2.pdf

Ofcourse in real life I have more than 2 folders.
I thought a for loop using `os.rename()` would work but I can't get it to change multiple files.

Here's what I tried

```py
import os

# assign directory
directory = 'all Student folders'

# iterate over files 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
  for filename in files:
    if filename =='work.pdf':
      os.rename('work.pdf', homework1.pdf')
```

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the file in the dir where it is.

```py
import os

# assign directory
directory = "all Student folders"

# iterate over files

for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name == "Work.pdf":
            os.rename(f"{root}/{file_name}", f"{root}/homework1.pdf")
        else:
            new_name = file_name.replace(f"Work", "homework")
            os.rename(f"{root}/{file_name}", f"{root}/{new_name}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Fioh! It worked! Now I can manipulate it and use when I need.  If you have some time I'd really appreciate if you could explain the script for us newbies. Or direct me to where I can learn more..

Comment: f"" is named f-string and allows to template a string

Comment: os.walk retrive for each root the folders and files it contains. We don't use folders so put underscore as variable name. When we move a file, the filename is not enough, you need to specify its location (root).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense I couldn't move into the different folders as I was just using file name. Brilliant!